# How to fix the Scanner to work inside a while in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I'm doing a simple program that "reads fortunes" for fun!
But, I can't seem to get my scanner to read the name of the person the second time onwards,

should I close the scanner? if so, in which part? **I tried** closing it at the end of the `repeat==true` loop and it didn't quite work.

```java
do{
    int n = rand.nextInt(50);
    int m = rand.nextInt(50);
    int o = rand.nextInt(50); 

    System.out.println("blah blah fortune");
    System.out.println("input your name"); // This part doesn't work the second time
    String name = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println();
    Prediction(name,n,m,o);
    System.out.println();

    do{
        System.out.println("do you wish to guess another fortune?");
        System.out.println("1 is yes other number no");
        //this part I will omit tests if the answer is valid and if it should repeat itself, it works for now.
    }
    while(!valid);
}
while (repeat==true);
```

Right now it skips the option to write the name and simply tells a fortune with a blank space as name, but the loop is working fine otherwise.

It should ask for the name of the next person whose fortune it will read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do{
int n = rand.nextInt(50);
int m = rand.nextInt(50);
int o = rand.nextInt(50); 

System.out.println("blah blah fortune");
System.out.println("input your name"); // This part doesn't work the second time
String name = scanner.next();

System.out.println();
Prediction(name,n,m,o);
System.out.println();

 System.out.println("do you wish to guess another fortune?");
    System.out.println("1 is yes other number no");
    //this part I will omit tests if the answer is valid and if it should repeat 
   itself, it works for now.


 }
 while (repeat==true);
```

use scanner.next() instead of nextLine(), nextLine() will take empty line as input next time onwards, so use next(). that is why it is not accepting the input. You can achieve the same functionality with one while loop only, but not sure what your requirement is.

Comment: I just did and it worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for interacting with `Scanner`. I would take another look at your loops (it isn't clear what the inner `do...while()` loop is doing) and what else is going on in your other code (what is `Prediction`? is there a bug with how you're setting `valid`?).

Here's a really simple loop for `Scanner` that loops forever, ask for a name, print the name:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("input your name");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
} while (true);
```

Comment: I just changed scanner.nextLine() to scanner.next() and it worked. But I'm very curious as to how that one works and my previous one didn't. I'll definitely search more about the subject to find out! Thank you very much for your answer.